# Is there a way to ignore first symbol using BufferedReader

Tags: java, json, parsing, url, bufferedreader

I try to get data in JSON format from url, but displayed data starts with [, is there any way to ignore first symbol using BufferedReader?

Code: http://pastebin.com/eGQGVPY3

Comment: Please include the relevant code directly in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To skip characters, use the `BufferedReader` `skip` method:

```
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
reader.skip(1);
```

This will work at any point in the stream (not just at the beginning).

Answer (score 0):

Returning `buffer.substring(1)` instead of `buffer.toString()` should achieve what you want.

Comment: ... but, *"never assume!"* **Check** that first byte to see if it is actually the character you expect!